Partial text assertion for elements using Detox
I'm using Detox to test my react native app. I identify my text element by the id and want to assert that the text contains SOME text.
I only want partial text check which .toHaveText("blah") doesn't allow.
The element has text 0 minutes / X minutes , I purely want to check that the element contains 0 minutes and im not interested in the X minutes (more specifically this second bit can change and my test will fail if i try to predict what X will be)
Am i missing something ?
.toHaveText checks the whole string, I just want to check part of the string

I have solved my issue by using the getAttibutes method and then using jestExpect to make the assertion
jestExpect(attributes.text).toContain('0 minutes');
